# Python - loop to increment a value in list append to another list just add sum's total

Tags: python, list, loops, increment

people! I'm trying to code a Space Invaders Python program to learning purposes but keep stumbling in *list* and *data manipulation* issues inside loops.
I just created a Class Squid to envelope the data for a circle to PyGame in the form: RGB, [X,Y] int

```
class Space_Ship:

    def space_ship():

        space_ship_X = 100
        space_ship_Y = 550
        space_ship_color = (255, 255, 255)
        space_ship_radius = 10
        space_ship = space_ship_color, [space_ship_X, space_ship_Y], space_ship_radius

        return space_ship
```

```
   class Squid:

    def squid():
        squid_X = 100
        squid_Y = 100
        squid_radius = 10
        squid_color = (255, 0, 0)
        squid = [squid_color, [squid_X, squid_Y], squid_radius]
        
        return squid
```

I need a squid's squad later, so I created an empty list and tried to increment the squid_X value before adding the "squid" to the list, but the counter just sums the total (600) and add it to every element in the list... [(255, 0, 0), [**600**, 100], 10]

```
from invader_squid.squid import Squid
from space_ship.space_ship import Space_Ship

import pygame
from pygame.constants import K_LEFT, K_RIGHT

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders - for poors")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

color_background = (0, 0, 0)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

''' space contenders '''
space_ship = Space_Ship.space_ship()
squid = Squid.squid()

''' game logic '''
space_ships = 1
squids = 10
crabs = 10
octopusses = 5
mother_ships = 3
```

Loop:

```
squids = 10
squadron_squids = []

i = 0
while i < squids:
    print('squid ' + str( squid[1][0]))

    squid[1][0] += 50

    print('New squid ' + str( squid[1][0]))

    squadron_squids.append(squid)

    i += 1

print('squid_X: ' + str(squid[1][0]) + '\nsquadron_squids ' + str(squadron_squids))
```

Game Loop

```
loop = True

while loop:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    # mandatory exit condition
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            loop = False

    # screen draw
    screen.fill(color_background)
    # space_ship
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, *space_ship) # *args 'scatter'
    # squid
    '''for i in range(squids):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, squadron_squids[i])
    '''
    ''' 
        MOVEMENT
        user input - move left or right
        circle can't surpass screen size
    '''
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        space_ship[1][0] -= 5
        if space_ship[1][0] < 10:
            space_ship[1][0] = 10
    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        space_ship[1][0] += 5
        if space_ship[1][0] > 790:
            space_ship[1][0] = 790
    
    pygame.display.update()
    

pygame.quit()
```

Print output:

```
squid_X 100
New squid_X 150
squid_X 150    
New squid_X 200
squid_X 200    
New squid_X 250
squid_X 250    
New squid_X 300
squid_X 300
New squid_X 350
squid_X 350
New squid_X 400
squid_X 400
New squid_X 450
squid_X 450
New squid_X 500
squid_X 500
New squid_X 550
squid_X 550
New squid_X 600

squid_X: 600
squadron_squids [[(255, 0, 0), [600, 100], 10], [(255, 0, 0), [600, 100], 10], [(255, 0, 0), [600, 100], 10], [(255, 0, 0), [600, 100], 10], [(255, 0, 0), [600, 100], 10], [(255, 0, 0), [600, 100], 10], [(255, 0, 0), [600, 100], 10], [(255, 0, 0), [600, 100], 10], [(255, 0, 0), [600, 100], 10], [(255, 0, 0), [600, 100], 10]]
```

Thanks in advance!
Any reading source to deepen the subject will be welcome!

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. 
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Comment: Very simply, you need to return to your materials on classes and instances, and learn the basics of using the concept, before you dive into implementing it in a wider context, such as a game.  A class with no `__init__` method is a heavy indication that either (1) you are unclear about how to use a class, (2) your concept should not be a class at all, or (3) you have a strange application, and would ask something more esoteric than how to handle a cumulative sum.

Comment: This is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  Asking for reading references is *specifically* listed as off-topic.  However, once you've grasped the basics of class and instance, you might try looking at the facilities of PyGame and other animation support packages.

Comment: The code you provided does not work.  Variable `squid` is not defined in `print('squid ' + str( squid[1][0]))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my suggestion:

Use a class `Squid` as a blueprint for squids and create squid **instances** from your class. Each squid instance has a position, a radius (with a default if you don't specify it) and a color (also with a default).

We then generate new squids and add them to a list, our squad. While doing so, we use the iteration index as our respective X position, while keeping the Y value constant - just for the sake of example.

```py
class Squid:
    def __init__(self, x, y, radius = 10, color = (255, 0, 0)):
        # bind all the values passed in this function to the object we're constructing here
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
    
    def __str__(self):
        # What happens when we call str(mySquid)?
        # Let's return something human readible
        # You can compare this to the output when calling repr(mySquid)
        return f'Squid([x={self.x}, y={self.y}], r={self.radius}, col={self.color})'

num_squids = 10
squad = []

# repeat num_squids=10 times
y = 10
for i in range(num_squids):
    sq = Squid(i, y)
    squad.append(sq)
    print(f'Squid {i+1} is ready: {sq}!')

print()
print("Here is my squad...")
for squid in squad:
    print(str(squid))
```

Output:

```
Squid 1 is ready: Squid([x=0, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))!
Squid 2 is ready: Squid([x=1, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))!
Squid 3 is ready: Squid([x=2, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))!
Squid 4 is ready: Squid([x=3, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))!
Squid 5 is ready: Squid([x=4, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))!
Squid 6 is ready: Squid([x=5, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))!
Squid 7 is ready: Squid([x=6, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))!
Squid 8 is ready: Squid([x=7, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))!
Squid 9 is ready: Squid([x=8, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))!
Squid 10 is ready: Squid([x=9, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))!

Here is my squad...
Squid([x=0, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))
Squid([x=1, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))
Squid([x=2, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))
Squid([x=3, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))
Squid([x=4, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))
Squid([x=5, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))
Squid([x=6, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))
Squid([x=7, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))
Squid([x=8, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))
Squid([x=9, y=10], r=10, col=(255, 0, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It's perfect, but I keep confused by the sum issue in my code. Any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid the code in your post isn't complete. In your `while` loop, you're using a variable `squid` which isn't defined anywhere. So the code itself won't run like this. You can update the post and I can take a closer look with you

Comment: I'm only take a fragment. Now its complete. I really appreciate your effort and time and I will take seriously the advices.